# How to select a cell A3 in Excel using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I want to select the Cell A3 using VB.net..

I tried doing this by:

```
sheet.Range("A3:A3").Select()
```

But this gives an exception = Select method of Range Class Failed !

What is the problem and how to do it ?

Please help.. I am waiting for the reply !

Comment: You said you are using VB.NET in the question, but you have also tagged it as Excel VBA.  Which are you using?

Comment: Would you post all of the code for your module, please? I suspect that sheet was not initialized correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program works for me in VB.NET, I agree with **rajah9**, check the other aspects.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
        oSheet.Range("A3").Select()
        oExcel.ActiveCell.Value = "Put text here"

        oBook.SaveAs("C:\Path\testinterop.xlsx")
        oExcel.Quit()

    End Sub
End Class
```

(based on, and drawn in part from, examples [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247412))

Comment: Actually I figured out the problem myself.. I had to select the sheet first in order to select the range.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant Excel VBA try this:

```
sheet.Range("A3").Select
```

You can just specify the cell if all you want is one cell.

Comment: Actually, it works when you have a reference to some sheet stored in a variable called "sheet".  What you are thinking of is ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select